# Email to HTTP call API?

Tags: email, monitoring

I am looking for some simple API that I could send email to and it would send HTTP GET request to a designated URL?

Does something like that exist? Its fairly difficult to setup email monitoring using .NET (setting up windows service , POP3/IMAP access etc).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you checked mailhooks (http://www.mailhooks.com/)? Is it what are you looking for?

Comment: Great! This is exactly what I need. I just need to test if it works and how reliable it is :)

Comment: Domain is unused. Please remove answer, or get new domain for the app.